# How to Pass Entries 6 times in future date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

I am working on a Loan Application, The application disburses loan to customer and this is working well. But the interest is to calculated everymonth. Interet is calculated on days based on the day the customer loan is disbursed. Like a customer loan can be disbursed on 15th of January 2021 now, the next interest will be calculated on 14th of february 2021, How do i get this saved and also called from database. i intend using Hangfire.  what i intend using is below, but if there is another efficient way, please me know.

```
double tenor = Convert.ToDouble(gMApprovedLoan.Tenor); // Tenor is assumed to be in months
                double no_Of_Months = tenor;
                double interest_rate = Convert.ToDouble(gMApprovedLoan.Interest_Rate) / 100;
                double Interest = (Amount * interest_rate) / no_Of_Months; 
            double NetAmount = Interest + Amount;
            new_balance = account_balance - Amount;
DateTime dt_Today = DateTime.Now;
            
DateTime first_Repayment_Date = dt_Today.AddMonths(1);
                DateTime second_Repayment_Date = dt_Today.AddMonths(2);
                DateTime third_Repayment_Date = dt_Today.AddMonths(3);
                DateTime fourth_Repayment_Date = dt_Today.AddMonths(4);
                DateTime fifth_Repayment_Date = dt_Today.AddMonths(5);
                DateTime sixth_Repayment_Date = dt_Today.AddMonths(6);
```

Loans is disbursed for 6months period. The dates above are date intended to call from Hangfire to calculate interest.

Please is there any other efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to loop through the no_Of_Months and add the new date to a list?

```
List<DateTime> Months = new List<DateTime>();
for(int i = 1; i <= no_Of_Months; i++)
{
    Months.Add(dt_Today.AddMonths(i));
}
```